# How to split a struct into chunks in order to save the bytes to another data structure in C/C++?

Tags: c++, struct, stack-trace, memcpy

I am trying to split a struct that is size 1536 into three equal size chunks of 512 bytes so that it can be saved to a virtual disk. The buffer size of the virtual disk is limited to 512 bytes. There is an issue when offsetting the pointer but I can't figure out why.

Here is the SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bitset>

#define SECTOR_SIZE  512
#define NUM_SECTORS  10000

typedef struct sector {
  char data[SECTOR_SIZE];
} Sector;

static Sector* disk;

struct dataBitmap {
    /* sizeof myBits = 1228 bytes */
    std::bitset<9795> myBits;
    /* 308 bytes not accounted for */
    char emptyData[308];
    /* dataBitmap will now perfectly overlay 3 sectors of disk */

} dataMap;

void Disk_Write(int sector, char* buffer)  {
    // quick error checks
    if((sector < 0) || (sector >= NUM_SECTORS) || (buffer == NULL)) {
        std::cout << "Error!";
    }
    // copy the memory for the user
    if((memcpy((void*)(disk + sector), (void*)buffer, sizeof(Sector))) == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error!";;
    }
}

void Update_Bitmaps() {
    char * bytes = (char*) malloc(512);

    std::cout << "size of dataMap: " << sizeof(dataMap) << '\n';

    const void* a = &dataMap;
    const void* b = (const void*)((char*)a + 512);

    /* data bitmap is 3 times the size of regular sector */
    memcpy(&bytes, b, 512);
    //Disk_Write(2, (char *) bytes); /* offset for data bitmap is 2 */

    memcpy(&bytes, (char *) &dataMap + 512, 512);
    Disk_Write(2, (char *) bytes);

    //memcpy(&bytes, (char *) &dataMap.myBits + 1024, 512);
    //Disk_Write(2, (char *) bytes);

    free(bytes);
}

int main()
{
    Update_Bitmaps();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

```
size of dataMap: 1536
      0 [main] BitSet 8276 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: 
      Dumping stack trace to BitSet.exe.stackdump

Process returned 35584 (0x8B00)   execution time : 0.464 s
```

I realize this is C-style code but I don't know how else to copy bytes in this manner. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory for `disk`.

```
int main()
{
    disk = malloc(sizeof(*disk)*NUM_SECTORS); // Allocate memory for disk
    Update_Bitmaps();
    free(disk);           // Free the allocated memory.
    return 0;
}
```

Also, the following lines are not correct.

```
memcpy(&bytes, b, 512);
//Disk_Write(2, (char *) bytes); /* offset for data bitmap is 2 */

memcpy(&bytes, (char *) &dataMap + 512, 512);
```

They need to be

```
memcpy(bytes, b, 512);
//     ^^ just bytes, not &bytes.
//Disk_Write(2, (char *) bytes); /* offset for data bitmap is 2 */

memcpy(bytes, (char *) &dataMap + 512, 512);
//     ^^ just bytes, not &bytes.
```